# carousal jquery not working in single file

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

my carousal works properly in the js fiddle 
but when i put all my js, html and css code in a single file it does not work properly

working code

http://jsfiddle.net/9Dr7T/61/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/9Dr7T/61/

single code does not work which i am providing below...
but when i do in js fiddle its working
http://jsfiddle.net/ApeDd/
the problem is if i save it in my machine and open it in chrome its not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <!-- End MS Site Pinning-->
        <link href="css/carousel-smMags.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>


          div { color:red; }




a, img{border: 1px solid red;}


.carousel-hdr  {
    width:806px;
    margin:46px auto 0;
}
.carousel-hdr .bold {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #3f4444;
    font-weight:400;
}
.carousel-hdr .rightlink {
    font-weight:300;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.carousel-hdr .dark-double {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.magHeroCarousel {
    color: #999999;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 260px; /* note - change to 280 when sprites/reading list is functioning */
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 25px 0 0 0;
    }

.magHeroCarousel .opaque.caroSmallLeft, 
.magHeroCarousel .opaque.caroSmallRight {
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 43px;
    z-index: 101;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: transparent;
    /*background-image: url(http://imgs.zinio.com/www/images/ui/grid-carousel-nav.png);*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    }
.magHeroCarousel .opaque.caroSmallLeft:hover, 
.magHeroCarousel .opaque.caroSmallRight:hover {
    /*background-image: url(http://imgs.zinio.com/www/images/ui/grid-carousel-nav-hover.png); */
    }

.magHeroCarousel .opaque.caroSmallLeft {
    background-position: 0px 96px;
    background-color: green;
    left: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;

    }

.magHeroCarousel .opaque.caroSmallRight {
    background-position: -43px 96px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color:red;
    height:300px;
        border: 1px solid black;

    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 62px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer img {
    width:185px;
   /* height:auto;*/
    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer .grouping {
    height: 300px;
    }
.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer .active {
    margin-left: 31px;  
    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer .grouping div a {
    margin-right: 26px;
    display:block;
    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer .grouping a {
    margin-right: 26px;
    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer .grouping :last-child a {
    margin-right: 52px;
    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer div {
    float: left;
    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer div p {
    margin: 8px 0 0 0;
    display: none;
    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer div.active p {
    display: block;
    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer div p span {
    background: url(http://imgs.zinio.com/www/images/sprites/carouselSprite.png) no-repeat;
    padding-left: 50px;
    color:#888888;
    font-size:10px;
    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer div p :first-child {
    background-position: 0 -71px;
    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer div p :last-child {
    background-position: 0 -47px;
    }

.magHeroCarousel .caroContainer p :first-child {
    margin: 0 7px 0 0;
    }
.sprites {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}    
.fave span {
    margin-right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.read span {
    margin-right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}



​




        </style>

        <script>

/************************************* 
 *   z-carousel.jquery.js
 */




(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.zCarousel = function() {

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                $kids = $this.children("div"),
                prevBtn = document.createElement("div"),
                nextBtn = document.createElement("div"),
                pagerWidth, childLength, childWidth, leftMagTitle, rightMagTitle, forPrependingOne, forAppendingOne, $prevArticleBlock, $nextArticleBlock, link;

            $kids.addClass("caroContainer");
            prevBtn.setAttribute("class", "caroSmallLeft");
            nextBtn.setAttribute("class", "caroSmallRight");

            function lazyLoad() {
                var $active = $this.find(".active"),
                    $currentImg = $active.find('img');

                $currentImg.each(function(i) {
                    $($currentImg[i]).attr('src', $($currentImg[i]).data('lazyload'))
                })
            }

            if ($this.attr("data-carouselType") === "magazineHero") {
                $(prevBtn).addClass("opaque");
                $(nextBtn).addClass("opaque");
                this.appendChild(prevBtn);
                this.appendChild(nextBtn);
                pagerWidth = $(prevBtn).width();
                childLength = $kids.children().length;
                $kids.css("left", pagerWidth + "px").children("div").addClass("grouping");
                childWidth = $kids.children("div").width();
                leftMagTitle = document.createElement("div");
                rightMagTitle = document.createElement("div");
                prevBtn.appendChild(leftMagTitle);
                nextBtn.appendChild(rightMagTitle);
                $kids.width(childLength * childWidth);
                $kids.children(":first-child").addClass("active");
                $kids.css("left", (pagerWidth - $this.find(".caroContainer").children("div").width()) + "px");

                forPrependingOne = $kids.children(":eq(" + (childLength - 1) + ")").clone();
                $kids.children(":eq(" + (childLength - 1) + ")").remove();
                $kids.prepend(forPrependingOne);

                $kids.click(function(e) {
                    link = $(e.target).parents(this).children("a").attr("href");
                    if ($(e.target).parents(this) && e.target.tagName !== "IMG" && e.target.tagName !== "INPUT" && e.target.tagName !== "A" && link !== undefined) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        document.location = link;
                    }
                });

                lazyLoad();

                $(prevBtn).click(function() {
                    forPrependingOne = $kids.children(":eq(" + (childLength - 1) + ")").clone();
                    $kids.children(":eq(" + (childLength - 1) + ")").remove();
                    $kids.prepend(forPrependingOne);
                    $kids.animate({
                        left: '-=' + childWidth
                    }, 0).animate({
                        left: '+=' + childWidth
                    }, 250);
                    $kids.children(".active").removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
                    $(leftMagTitle).empty().append($kids.find(".grouping.active").prev("div").children(".articleInfo").children("h3").clone()).append($kids.find(".grouping.active").prev("div").children(".articleInfo").children(":first-child").clone());
                    $(rightMagTitle).empty().append($kids.find(".grouping.active").next("div").children(".articleInfo").children("h3").clone()).append($kids.find(".grouping.active").next("div").children(".articleInfo").children(":first-child").clone());
                    lazyLoad();
                });

                $(nextBtn).click(function() {
                    forAppendingOne = $kids.children(":eq(0)").clone();
                    $kids.children(":eq(0)").remove();
                    $kids.append(forAppendingOne);
                    $kids.animate({
                        left: '+=' + childWidth
                    }, 0).animate({
                        left: '-=' + childWidth
                    }, 250);
                    $kids.children(".active").removeClass("active").next().addClass("active");
                    lazyLoad();
                });
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));




/************************************* 
 *   zin-carousel2.js 
 */





;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    /************************************* 
     *   Jquery Plugin Setup 
     */
    $.fn.zinCarousel = function(settings) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.zinCarousel.defaultSettings, settings || {});
        return this.each(function() {
            var o = $.extend(true, {}, settings),
                $elem = $(this),
                caro = new Carousel(o, $elem);
            caro.init();
        });
    };

    /************************************* 
     *   Default Settings 
     */
    $.fn.zinCarousel.defaultSettings = { /* settings */
        keyboadNav: true,
        handleSubData: false,
        autoPlay: false,
        autoPlayDuration: 4000,
        animationSpeed: 250,
        easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
        /* elements */
        body: 'body',
        viewPort: '#view-port',
        parent: '.carousel_ul',
        kids: '.carousel_ul li',
        firstKid: '.carousel_ul li:first',
        lastKid: '.carousel_ul li:last-of-type',
        prevBtn: '.caroLeft',
        nextBtn: '.caroRight',
        active: '.active',
        startPosition: ':nth-child(4)',
        leftMagTitle: '#leftMagTitle',
        rightMagTitle: '#rightMagTitle'
    };

    /************************************* 
     *   Main Carousel Object {}
     */

    function Carousel(settings, elem) { /* Settings */
        this.settings = settings;
        this.animationSpeed = this.settings.animationSpeed;
        this.startPosition = this.settings.startPosition;
        this.handleSubData = this.settings.handleSubData;
        this.autoplay = this.settings.autoPlay;
        this.autoplayDuration = this.settings.autoPlayDuration; /* Elements */
        // this.$elem = $(elem);
        this.$body = $(this.settings.body);
        this.$viewPort = $(this.settings.viewPort);
        this.$parent = $(this.settings.parent);
        this.$$kids = $(this.settings.kids);
        this.$prevBtn = $(this.settings.prevBtn);
        this.$nextBtn = $(this.settings.nextBtn);
        this.$leftMagTitle = $(this.settings.leftMagTitle);
        this.$rightMagTitle = $(this.settings.rightMagTitle); /* strings */
        this.parentString = this.settings.parent;
        this.firstKidString = this.settings.firstKid;
        this.lastKidString = this.settings.lastKid;
        this.active = this.settings.active;
        this.activeString = this.active.replace(/^\.+/, ''); /* local settings */
        this.itemWidth = this.$$kids.outerWidth(true);
        this.leftIndent = parseInt(this.$parent.css('left'), 10);
        this.easingStyle = this.settings.easing;
        this.leftOffset = this.$parent.css('left');
        this.isAutoPlaying = false;
        return this;
    }

    /************************************* 
     *   Methods
     */
    Carousel.prototype = {

        init: function(elem) {
            // set the active element
            this.$parent.children(this.startPosition).addClass(this.activeString);
            this.lazyLoad();
            this.setEvents(this);
            if (this.handleSubData) {
                this.setMagTitle();
            }
            if (this.autoplay) {
                this.autoPlay();
                this.isAutoPlaying = true;
            }
        },

        setEvents: function(_this) {
            // Previous Button Event
            this.$prevBtn.on('click', function(e) {
                _this.prevAction();
            });

            // Next Button Event
            this.$nextBtn.on('click', function(e) {
                _this.nextAction();
            });

            // Capture click on viewport above image
            this.$viewPort.on('click', function(e) {
                _this.mainMediaClick(e);
            });

            this.$viewPort.on('mouseover', function(e) {
                if (_this.isAutoPlaying) {
                    _this.stopAutoPlay();
                }
            });

            this.$viewPort.on('mouseout', function(e) {
                if (_this.autoplay) {
                    _this.autoPlay();
                }
            });

            // Keyboard Navigation Event
            if (this.settings.keyboadNav) {
                _this.$body.on('keydown', function(e) {
                    _this.keyboardNav(e);
                });
            }

        },

        prevAction: function() {
            this.animate('prev');
        },

        nextAction: function() {
            this.animate('next');
        },

        keyboardNav: function(e) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                // left arrow
            case 37:
                this.prevAction();
                break;
                // right arrow
            case 39:
                this.nextAction();
                break;
            }
        },

        autoPlay: function() {
            var _this = this;
            if (this.autoplay) {
                this.run = window.setInterval(function() {
                    _this.nextAction();
                }, this.autoplayDuration);
                this.isAutoPlaying = true;
            }
        },

        stopAutoPlay: function() {
            this.isAutoPlaying = false;
            window.clearInterval(this.run);
        },

        clearAutoPlay: function() {
            clearInterval(this.run);
            this.autoPlay();
        },

        mainMediaClick: function(e) {
            var link = this.findActive().find('a').attr('href');
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location = link;
        },

        findActive: function() {
            return this.$parent.find(this.active);
        },

        lazyLoad: function() {
            var $active = this.findActive(),
                $currentImg = $active.find('img'),
                $nextImg = $active.next('li').find('img'),
                $nextImgP = $active.next('li').next('li').find('img'),
                $previousImg = $active.prev('li').find('img'),
                $previousImgP = $active.prev('li').prev('li').find('img');

            $nextImg.attr('src', $nextImg.data('lazyload'));
            $nextImgP.attr('src', $nextImgP.data('lazyload'));
            $previousImg.attr('src', $previousImg.data('lazyload'));
            $previousImgP.attr('src', $previousImgP.data('lazyload'));
            $currentImg.attr('src', $currentImg.data('lazyload'));
        },

        setMagTitle: function() {
            var articleInfoPrev = this.findActive().prev('li').children('.articleInfo').children().clone(),
                articleInfoNext = this.findActive().next('li').children('.articleInfo').children().clone();
            this.$leftMagTitle.find('div').empty().append(articleInfoPrev);
            this.$rightMagTitle.find('div').empty().append(articleInfoNext);
        },

        swapKids: function(direction) {
            var _this = this,
                firstKid = $(this.firstKidString),
                lastKid = $(this.lastKidString);
            if (direction === 'prev') {
                _this.$parent.css({
                    'left': _this.leftOffset
                });
                firstKid.before(lastKid);
            } else if (direction === 'next') {
                _this.$parent.css({
                    'left': _this.leftOffset
                });
                lastKid.after(firstKid);
            }
        },

        animate: function(direction) {
            var _this = this,
                current = this.findActive(),
                left_indent, currentDirection, articleInfo = current.children('.articleInfo'),
                animateParent = $(this.parentString + ':not(:animated)');

            if (direction === 'prev') {
                left_indent = (this.leftIndent + this.itemWidth) + 'px';
                currentDirection = current.prev();
            } else if (direction === 'next') {
                left_indent = (this.leftIndent - this.itemWidth) + 'px';
                currentDirection = current.next();
            }

            articleInfo.css({
                'display': 'none'
            });

            animateParent.animate({
                'left': left_indent
            }, this.animationSpeed, this.easingStyle, function() {
                _this.swapKids(direction);
                currentDirection.children('.articleInfo').end().addClass(_this.activeString);
                current.removeClass(_this.activeString);
                _this.lazyLoad();
                // articleInfo.css({
                //     'display': 'block'
                // });
                if (_this.handleSubData) {
                    _this.setMagTitle();
                }
                if (_this.autoplay) {
                    _this.clearAutoPlay();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    $.extend($.easing, {
        def: 'easeOutQuad',
        swing: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            //alert($.easing.default);
            return $.easing[$.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
        },
        easeInQuad: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return c * (t /= d) * t + b;
        },
        easeOutQuad: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return -c * (t /= d) * (t - 2) + b;
        },
        easeInOutQuad: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * t * t + b;
            return -c / 2 * ((--t) * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
        },
        easeInCubic: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return c * (t /= d) * t * t + b;
        },
        easeOutCubic: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t + 1) + b;
        },
        easeInOutCubic: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * t * t * t + b;
            return c / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * t + 2) + b;
        },
        easeInQuart: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return c * (t /= d) * t * t * t + b;
        },
        easeOutQuart: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return -c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t - 1) + b;
        },
        easeInOutQuart: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * t * t * t * t + b;
            return -c / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * t * t - 2) + b;
        },
        easeInQuint: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return c * (t /= d) * t * t * t * t + b;
        },
        easeOutQuint: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t * t + 1) + b;
        },
        easeInOutQuint: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * t * t * t * t * t + b;
            return c / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * t * t * t + 2) + b;
        },
        easeInSine: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return -c * Math.cos(t / d * (Math.PI / 2)) + c + b;
        },
        easeOutSine: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return c * Math.sin(t / d * (Math.PI / 2)) + b;
        },
        easeInOutSine: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return -c / 2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI * t / d) - 1) + b;
        },
        easeInExpo: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return (t == 0) ? b : c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t / d - 1)) + b;
        },
        easeOutExpo: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return (t == d) ? b + c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t / d) + 1) + b;
        },
        easeInOutExpo: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            if (t == 0) return b;
            if (t == d) return b + c;
            if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b;
            return c / 2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --t) + 2) + b;
        },
        easeInCirc: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t /= d) * t) - 1) + b;
        },
        easeOutCirc: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t = t / d - 1) * t) + b;
        },
        easeInOutCirc: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return -c / 2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t * t) - 1) + b;
            return c / 2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t -= 2) * t) + 1) + b;
        },
        easeInElastic: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            var s = 1.70158;
            var p = 0;
            var a = c;
            if (t == 0) return b;
            if ((t /= d) == 1) return b + c;
            if (!p) p = d * .3;
            if (a < Math.abs(c)) {
                a = c;
                var s = p / 4;
            }
            else var s = p / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(c / a);
            return -(a * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t -= 1)) * Math.sin((t * d - s) * (2 * Math.PI) / p)) + b;
        },
        easeOutElastic: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            var s = 1.70158;
            var p = 0;
            var a = c;
            if (t == 0) return b;
            if ((t /= d) == 1) return b + c;
            if (!p) p = d * .3;
            if (a < Math.abs(c)) {
                a = c;
                var s = p / 4;
            }
            else var s = p / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(c / a);
            return a * Math.pow(2, -10 * t) * Math.sin((t * d - s) * (2 * Math.PI) / p) + c + b;
        },
        easeInOutElastic: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            var s = 1.70158;
            var p = 0;
            var a = c;
            if (t == 0) return b;
            if ((t /= d / 2) == 2) return b + c;
            if (!p) p = d * (.3 * 1.5);
            if (a < Math.abs(c)) {
                a = c;
                var s = p / 4;
            }
            else var s = p / (2 * Math.PI) * Math.asin(c / a);
            if (t < 1) return -.5 * (a * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t -= 1)) * Math.sin((t * d - s) * (2 * Math.PI) / p)) + b;
            return a * Math.pow(2, -10 * (t -= 1)) * Math.sin((t * d - s) * (2 * Math.PI) / p) * .5 + c + b;
        },
        easeInBack: function(x, t, b, c, d, s) {
            if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
            return c * (t /= d) * t * ((s + 1) * t - s) + b;
        },
        easeOutBack: function(x, t, b, c, d, s) {
            if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
            return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * ((s + 1) * t + s) + 1) + b;
        },
        easeInOutBack: function(x, t, b, c, d, s) {
            if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
            if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * (t * t * (((s *= (1.525)) + 1) * t - s)) + b;
            return c / 2 * ((t -= 2) * t * (((s *= (1.525)) + 1) * t + s) + 2) + b;
        },
        easeInBounce: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            return c - $.easing.easeOutBounce(x, d - t, 0, c, d) + b;
        },
        easeOutBounce: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            if ((t /= d) < (1 / 2.75)) {
                return c * (7.5625 * t * t) + b;
            } else if (t < (2 / 2.75)) {
                return c * (7.5625 * (t -= (1.5 / 2.75)) * t + .75) + b;
            } else if (t < (2.5 / 2.75)) {
                return c * (7.5625 * (t -= (2.25 / 2.75)) * t + .9375) + b;
            } else {
                return c * (7.5625 * (t -= (2.625 / 2.75)) * t + .984375) + b;
            }
        },
        easeInOutBounce: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
            if (t < d / 2) return $.easing.easeInBounce(x, t * 2, 0, c, d) * .5 + b;
            return $.easing.easeOutBounce(x, t * 2 - d, 0, c, d) * .5 + c * .5 + b;
        }
    });
}(jQuery, window, document));








/************************************* 
 home.js
 */











$(document).ready(function() { /* small magazine carousel */
    $(".magHeroCarousel").zCarousel();

    /* large article hero  carousel */
    $(".carousel_container").zinCarousel({ /* settings */
        keyboadNav: true,
        autoPlay: false,
        autoPlayDuration: 1000,
        animationSpeed: 400,
        handleSubData: true,
        easing: "swing" /***** CORRECTION: comma deleted *****/
        //easeInOutExpo, swing, easeInOutBack, easeInOutElastic(1500),
    });

});​






        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper" style="width: 330px;">

        <!-- top sellers carousel -->
                <div class="magHeroCarousel" data-carouselType="magazineHero">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="specialHover">      
                                    <img src="img/grey.gif" data-lazyload="" width="200" height="187" alt="1" title="AppleMagazine" class="cover lazy" style="background-color: black;" />
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="specialHover">
                                    <img src="" data-lazyload="" width="200" height="187" alt="2" title="iPhone Life" class="cover lazy" style="background-color: yellow;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="specialHover">
                                <img src="" data-lazyload="" width="200" height="187" alt="3" title="Popular Science" class="cover lazy" style="background-color: pink;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

        <!-- deals carousel -->

        <!-- end magHeroCarousel -->

        </div><!--end wrapper -->

    </body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: @joequincy: i did not use any web server i just saved as .html file in desktop and opened in chrome did u try it.....

Comment: http://jamisondance.com/post/12857366951/running-local-javascript-files-in-chrome/

Comment: @joequincy: thanks for your reply...but where to put this commands --allow-file-access
--allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: In the shortcut to launch Chrome. If you're looking to develop a website, it's better to just get a webserver like [WAMPServer](http://www.wampserver.com/) and use it instead of messing with the way you launch Chrome.

Comment: @joequincy: but other jquery works fine....this is not working properly....wat to do

Comment: I just told you what to do. Basic jQuery is working because you're loading it from the internet. The stuff embedded in the HTML file is not, and Chrome is ignoring it.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Chrome blocks Javascript loaded using the `file://` protocol. (This includes any Javascript in a `.htm/.html` file loaded that way, or script files loaded by such a file using relative links)

This is a good security measure, which I do not advise bypassing. Especially if you are looking to develop websites on your local machine, I recommend installing a webserver ([WAMPServer](http://www.wampserver.com) is a very user-friendly package to get you started). When setting up WAMPServer, you will be prompted to set a folder for the root of your server. This folder will be where you place any files used in your website (WAMP defaults to `C:\WAMP\www`). Any files within that folder can then be accessed by opening your browser and navigating to `http://localhost/filename.extension` and will behave as if it was being loaded from an external server (with some exceptions, but those are outside the scope of this answer because you are unlikely to encounter them).

If you are still against installing a webserver, then you CAN switch Chrome into a mode that will allow local Javascript by creating a NEW shortcut to Chrome. Right-click on that shortcut, choose Properties, and in the Target field, add the following to the end (after the quotes):

```
 --allow-file-access --allow-file-access-from-files
```

But ONLY use that new shortcut in the specific instances when you are viewing those local files.
Launch Chrome normally whenever you're browsing the internet.